# How to get source version of containerd 1.3.3 via apt?

Tags: 18.04, apt, repository, software-sources

Package `containerd` in version 1.3.3 seems to be the most recent one for [Ubuntu Bionic](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/containerd) architecture `amd64`:

```
$ apt show containerd      
Package: containerd
Version: 1.3.3-0ubuntu1~18.04.4
Priority: optional
...
```

Unfortunately the sources are not available.

```
$ apt-get source containerd      
Reading package lists... Done
E: Unable to find a source package for containerd


$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
```

It seems like the [sources are only available for the most recent version](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/universe/source/Sources.gz). Which is 1.4.4. But this version is not available for `amd64`.

Is there a way of getting the sources for the recent containerd version 1.3.3 via apt ?

Comment: Containerd in 18.04 is in the Universe pocket. See [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Comment: @user535733 I've got the `universe` deb-src enabled for `bionic`, `bionic-updates` and `bionic-backports` on my 18.04 box and it **still** only finds source package `containerd-1.4.4`

Comment: ... in fact it looks like bionic/universe only provides the [1.2.6-0ubuntu1~18.04.2](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic/containerd) source while bionic-updates/universe only provides the [1.4.4-0ubuntu1~18.04.2](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic-updates/containerd) source

Comment: Sorry. I forgot `universe` above. But using it only enables me to download the source in version 1.4.4 as @steeldriver mentioned.